# Function with 3 IF conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been looking around but can't seem to get an IF function with 4 value ranges working in my spreadsheet.

I need an IF function that returns the following values:

- `0` if the number is between 0 and just below 1 (i.e. <1).
- `6` if the number is between 1 and below 2.
- `8` if the number is between 2 and below 3.
- `10` if the number is between 3 and 4.

Edit: `=IF(A4>=3,10,IF(AND(A4>=2,P4<3),8,IF(A4>=1,6,0)))`

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1351675/edit) your question to include functions you have tried. Also remember, that superuser is not a scripting service, we can halp you in finding flaws in your functions, but we do not write them for you.

Comment: =IF(AND(A4>=0,A4<1),0,IF(AND(A4>=1,A4<2),6,IF(AND(A4>=2,A4<3),8,IF(AND(A4>=3,A4<4),10,-1))))
Note that in your conditions you are not covering cases when number is less than 0 or more than 4

Comment: What is in P4 and why is that in the formula?

Answer (score 3):

For the case you describe, the `INDEX`/`MATCH` solution provided by cybernetic.nomad is probably the simplest. If the numbers are always exactly you described, the answer provided by Chris Rogers is even simpler.

I will try to answer the more general question of whether there is a way to check multiple conditions in a single function without nesting several `IF` functions. The [`IFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60655&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function, which I think was introduced in Excel 2016, lets you do that.

The function takes multiple pairs of parameters with each pair being a condition to be tested followed by the value to be returned if the condition is true. The function processes the parameter pairs starting with the first and continues until it finds a condition that is true.

```
=IFS(A4<0,NA(),A4<1,0,A4<2,6,A4<3,8,A4<4,10,TRUE,NA())
```

The function above will:

- Return an #N/A if A4 is less than 0 (you didn't say what should happen in that case).
- Return 0 if A4 is less than 1 (A4 must also be >=0, or the previous test would have been true).
- Return 6 if A4 is less than 2 (and also >=1).
- Return 8 if A4 is less than 3 (and also >=2).
- Return 10 if A4 is less than 4 (and also >=3).
- Return #N/A otherwise.

In this case, you can leave out the last two arguments (`,TRUE,NA()`) as `NA()` will be returned if none of the conditions are met.

Answer (score 2):

`INDEX/MATCH` can do this easily enough. Assuming the value to check is in `A4`:

```
=INDEX({0,6,8,10},MATCH(A4,{0,1,2,3,4}))
```

(note that this will return an error if the content of `A4` is below zero or above 4)

A brief explanation (at Fixer's request)

`MATCH(A4,{0,1,2,3,4})` will rank the value in `A4` in the array `{0,1,2,3,4}`, so any value such that `0 <= A4 < 1` will return 1; a value such that `1 <= A4 < 2` will return 2; and so on.

`INDEX({0,6,8,10},...` will take the value received from the `MATCH` and return the corresponding value from the array `{0,6,8,10}`, so if `MATCH` returns `1`, `INDEX` will return (in this case) `0`; if `MATCH` returns `2`, `INDEX` will return (in this case) `6`; and so on

To avoid the above mentioned error, the arrays can be expanded, for example:

```
=INDEX({"too low",0,6,8,10,"too high"},MATCH(A4,{-100,0,1,2,3,4,100}))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in Excel function for `IF` with multiple conditions. You can however use multiple nested `IF` statements. A very basic case:

```
IF(condition1,IF(condition2,value_if_true2,value_if_false2),value_if_false1)
```

alternatively:

```
IF(condition1,value_if_truet1,IF(condition2,value_if_true2,value_if_false2))
```

As you can see in `IF` statement you can replace either `value_if_true` or `value_if_false` or both with another `IF` statement and thus continue nesting conditions to achieve result you want.

Good example with explanation here:

https://exceljet.net/formula/nested-if-function-example

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the AND function.

```
=IF(A4>=3,10,IF(A4>=2,8,IF(A4>=1,6,0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

> - 0 if the number is between 0 and just below 1 (i.e. <1).
> - 6 if the number is between 1 and below 2.
> - 8 if the number is between 2 and below 3.
> - 10 if the number is between 3 and 4.

There is an easy way without `INDEX()` and `MATCH()`, `IFS()` or a nested `IF()`.

Looking at your formula you posted, you are testing cell `A4` and apart from `0`, the result follows the mathematical  equation pattern of `(the integer of A4 × 2) + 4` so try the following to do that

```
=IF(A4<1,0,(INT(A4)*2)+4))
```